# Add some fileds to the wp_posts table

Tags: plugins, database, customization

I need to extend some wp tables (wp_posts, wp_comments, wp_users) to store some additional fields.
I can't use metadata because I need to query those values directly via MySQL.
I need an help to choose if it's better to extend the original table or to define an additional one with those fields, with a 1-1 relationship to the original one.
This second case will require an additional JOIN.
Thanks.

eV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach (joining additional table) is better for several reasons.

- When plugin is not active, you won't retrieve it's data (or with other words, you won't select additional data unless you explicitly join it)
- It's more maintainable. You can alter your plugin table without altering posts table and vice versa.
- [The join most likely won't hurt performance, but may improve it if there are a lot of updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075890/storing-lots-of-user-information-into-one-mysql-table/7075949#7075949) - ([one more post on the same topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668544/what-are-the-benefits-of-vertical-partitioning-vs-horizontal-partitioning/6670352#6670352))

Comment: Thank you, the additional fields will have many updates. Thanks also for the useful links.

Answer (score 1):

Adding fields to WP's tables seems like a bad idea...what about using post meta and just JOINing on the post_meta table?

Comment: I need to have one record per element and not n records (or need to encode an array, because I need to query each field).